# Python: Nested loop not working

Tags: python, loops

I took the following code from another script and modified it to my needs. What I have to do is make the same query in Google Trends for different geographic locations and different periods of time.

```
import csv

read_list=open("GTrends Georreference.csv")

geo_list=csv.reader(read_list, delimiter=',')

import csv

read_list2=open("Dates.csv")

date_list=csv.reader(read_list2, delimiter=',')

#connect to Google
connector = pyGTrends(google_username, google_password)

for i in geo_list:

    geo=str(i)
    geo=geo[2:-2]

    for j in date_list:
        dat=str(j)
        dat=dat[2:-2]
        mon=dat.split('/')[-2]
        yr=dat[5:7]

#make request
        connector.request_report(query,"","",geo,dat)

#wait a random amount of time between requests to avoid bot detection
        #time.sleep(randint(1,3))

#download file
        connector.save_csv(path, query +"_"+ geo +"_"+ mon+"-"+yr)
```

However, when I run it, it only runs for the first element of the list of geographic references and all the periods, but then it stops. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much in advance.

Edit: The CVSs look like this:

The Georreference one:

```
US
US-AK
US-AL
US-AR
US-AK
US-CA
US-CO
US-CT
US-FL
US-GA
US-HI
US-IA
US-ID
US-IL
US-IN
US-KS
US-KY
US-LA
US-MA
```

The dates:

```
01/2004 3m
04/2004 3m
07/2004 3m
10/2004 3m
01/2005 3m
04/2005 3m
07/2005 3m
10/2005 3m
01/2006 3m
04/2006 3m
07/2006 3m
10/2006 3m
01/2007 3m
04/2007 3m
07/2007 3m
10/2007 3m
01/2008 3m
04/2008 3m
07/2008 3m
```

I have to say that without nesting the loops (i.e., using all the values of geo_list for one specific date) it works as it should. It's just the combination of both loops that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: can you print your `geo_list` and `date_list` before entering any loop?

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem isn't reproducible without a lot more code.  After all, if I ran this, it lacks a lot of the variables and the connector.  Could it be that bot detection or over-use of the API simply returns no response?

Comment: `query` does not vary in the loop.  Therefore it is constant.  Is that desirable behavior?

Comment: double check the type of `date_list`? It might be a generator

Comment: Both date_list and geo_list are taken from CSV files. That's almost all the code, query should remain constant and is inputted when the script starts.

Comment: Can you please update the post with how the csv looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it worked, but I overcame this issue by changing the way python imports the .CSVs:

```
import csv

with open ("GTrends Georreference.csv", "r") as f:
        reader=csv.reader(f)
        geo_list=list(reader)

import csv

with open ("Dates.csv") as f:
        reader=csv.reader(f)
        date_list=list(reader)
```

With that, it works like charm.